# Unit testing Angular router.events.pipe followed by subscribe

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I've following angular code:

```
changeMetaTags() {
  let metaData: any;
  this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(() => {
      let child = this.activatedRoute.firstChild;
      while (child) {
          if (child.firstChild) {
            child = child.firstChild;
          } else if (child.snapshot.data) {
            return child.snapshot.data;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
      }
      return null;
    })
  ).subscribe( (data: any) => {
    metaData = data;
    if (data['title']) {
      this.translate.get(data['title']).subscribe((data: string) => {
        this.seoService.updateTitle(data);
      })
    }
  });

  this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
    if (metaData['title']) {
      this.translate.get(metaData['title']).subscribe((metaData: string) => {
        this.seoService.updateTitle(metaData);
      })
    }
  });
}
```

I'm trying to write unit test case for above function, but unable to make progress. Can anyone please help to write jasmine unit test for changeMetaTags() function.

Also please comment if you need more details about the code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule#description and then `SpyLocation` to simulate router events (navigation), or you can mock `this.router.events` to be a plain `Subject<RouterEvent>` and push test events directly

Comment: Hello @Antoniossss, Thanks : ) .
this link helped me to write the test case for the function:
https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule#description